# Trying to use an inputted user var in an equation using HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to Javascript and am trying to create a form that computes a result using a specific equation.  I was trying to make var x the baseprice number that the user inputs and then subsequently use that var in an equation.  I am wondering if my problem is that I am missing submit input and then have x register on entry somehow?  This is what I have so far:

```
<input type="number" id="baseprice">

<br><br>

Result:

<p id="LESResult"></p>

<script>

var x = document.getElementById("baseprice").value;
var y = 100;
var d = 30;
var z = (x)/(y-d);
var m = z * y;
var num = m;
var n = num.toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("LESResult").innerHTML = n;

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code runs once, immediately when the page loads. You need to trigger that code in response to something the user does. There is an event called an ["input" event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) that is triggered by the user editing an input. Bind an event handler to your input as follows:

```
document.getElementById("baseprice").addEventListener("input", function () {
    var x = this.value;
    var y = 100;
    var d = 30;
    var z = (x) / (y - d);
    var m = z * y;
    var num = m;
    var n = num.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("LESResult").innerHTML = n;
});
```

Note that the first line of the function uses `this.value` rather than calling `.getElementById()` - within the event handling function `this` is a reference to the input element, so you don't need to call `.getElementById()` again.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8rq7ab71/

Other options would include binding to the "change" or "blur" events, both of which would be triggered only when the user tabs or clicks out of the input when they've finished editing, or adding a "Calculate" button and putting a "click" handler on it. See also: [the `addEventListener()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button and attach an event listener to it like this:

```
<input type="number" id="baseprice">
<button onclick="calculate_result()">submit</button>

<br><br>

Result:

<p id="LESResult"></p>

<script>

calculate_result = function() {
  var x = document.getElementById("baseprice").value;
  var y = 100;
  var d = 30;
  var z = (x)/(y-d);
  var m = z * y;
  var num = m;
  var n = num.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("LESResult").innerHTML = n;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks this was just what I was looking for!